# React native setup initial state for filter search buttons using immutable.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, immutable.js

I want to render list of filter option button for my search feature. So user can filter their search based on these price categories (cheap, normal, expensive)

The list of filter buttons I listed them in redux state like this

```
priceFilter:new (Record({
            options:new (Record({
                cheap:new (Record({
                    id:10,
                    text: 'Cheap'
                }))(),
                normal:new (Record({
                    id:30,
                    text: 'Normal'
                }))(),
                expensive:new (Record({
                    id:40,
                    text: 'Expensive'
                }))(),
            }))(),
        }))(),
```

But this doesnt work, I tried to access the cheap text using this but its undefined

```
this.props.search.priceFilter.options.map((option, index) =>
     <Text>{option.id} {option.text}</Text>
)
```

I tried console.log the props `this.props.search.priceFilter.options` also undefined

Are there something wrong with my initial state structure? is nested `Record` like this illegal? if so, Whats the proper structure?

Comment: Are you sure you are not forgetting to connect the component where you are using the search props? i would console.log(this.props.search) and if undefined comes out, that means that the component is not connected to the redux store. in that case let me know if you dont know how to achive this.

Comment: I added connect, I can access other state, which are not nested like this

Comment: what comes out when you call `console.log(this.props.search)` ?